# I can't access my sites after typing iptables -F command

Tags: iptables

write the following commands that I found on a website to release the ports for a server

```
iptables -I INPUT -p tcp -m tcp --dport 25565 -j ACCEPT
iptables -I INPUT -p udp -m udp --dport 25565 -j ACCEPT
iptables -I OUTPUT -p tcp -m tcp --dport 25565 -j ACCEPT
iptables -I OUTPUT -p udp -m udp --dport 25565 -j ACCEPT
netfilter-persistent save
iptables -F
```

After running the command "iptables -F", I lost access to my server and the websites hosted on it stopped working. After restarting the server, SSH and FTP access were restored, but my sites are still down. Is there any way to undo these commands or any solution to get my sites back up and running?

Comment: probably the default is Drop in Input and Output Chains.
use "iptables -I INPUT -j ACCEPT"  & "iptables -I OUTPUT -j ACCEPT"

Comment: it worked, thank you friend!

Answer (score 0):

The **"iptables -F"** command flushes all the rules from the iptables firewall, which means that all incoming and outgoing traffic to your server will be blocked until new rules are added.

To fix this issue, you need to add the necessary rules to iptables to allow traffic to your sites.

As temporary solution you may use:

```
iptables -I INPUT -j ACCEPT
iptables -I OUTPUT -j ACCEPT
```

But be aware that by using above rules, it will allow all incoming/outgoing traffic to your server, which can be a significant security risk. This rule effectively disables your firewall and removes all restrictions on incoming traffic, which can leave your server vulnerable to various types of attacks.

It's generally not recommended to allow all incoming/outgoing traffic in this way. Instead, you should carefully consider which ports and protocols you need to allow and configure your firewall accordingly.